# android: unwanted activity is shown previous to main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Im developing an Android application in Eclipse. It's very simple...just three or four activities. My app is named "GeoLocation".

When I start the application the main activity is shown..however, previously to this activity other one is displayed for 2 or 3 seconds...

The image is a small icon at the topleft and the app title at the topright.

I dont know nothing about this activity. It's not mine...I suposse it is some default activity provided by Eclipse IDE or something similar. How can I remove this activity or change it?

Thanks.

Comment: check your manifest file, which as intent filter with <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />, and look for android:name="<your_acitvity>" in your activity tag this will be your first screen shown in your application. If not change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some work before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); right? you layout wont load if you dont use that method, so doing work before that will make an empty layout to appear

Answer (score 0):

My main activity code is very simple:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.init_activity);
```

}

I did set a breakpoint and the unwanted activity is shown before onCreate is called.